# unable to set type shadowJar for gradle task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, shadowjar

I am using gradle v3.4 and shadowjar v1.2.4.  I added the following task but I get an error copied below when doing this.  I added a task of type ShadowJar in order to be able to generate different jar files from the same project.

Shadowjar works fine for me outside the context of this task.

**gradle**

```
    task someJar(type: ShadowJar) {
    group = "shadow"
    description = "some executable jar"
    mainClassName = 'com.some.client.SomeClient'
    main = 'com.some.client.SomeClient'
    manifest.attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.some.client.SomeClient'
    classifier = 'someClient'
   from(project.convention.getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention).sourceSets.main.output)
    configurations = [project.configurations.runtime]
    exclude('META-INF/INDEX.LIST', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA')
}
```

**error using stacktrace**

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'ShadowJar' for root project 'someporject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:85)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.getProperty(BasicScript.java:81)
        at build_2cp7m6fw08pxyu0f84a6pva88.run(/Users/continue/git/iso20022/build.gradle:202)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
```

Comment: https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/108#issuecomment-62638205

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Specifying the type as com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar instead of ShadowJar resolved the issue for me.

```
task someJar(type: com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar) {
```

Comment: alternatively use imports - the same way it works in Java!

Answer (score 4):

this would also work:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

task someJar(type: ShadowJar) {
    // ...
}
```